# execute command in while loop

Tags: postgresql

I have a postgres function which runs the following loop

`while x<=colnum LOOP`
      `EXECUTE

       'Update attendrpt set
                slot'||x||' = pres 
          from (SELECT branch, semester, attend_date , div,                         array_to_string(ARRAY_AGG(first_name||':'||alias_name||':'||lect_type||':'||
to_char(present,'99')),';') 
As pres
               from attend1 where lecture_slot_no ='||x||'
             group by  branch, semester, attend_date , div ) j 
          where attendrpt.branch=j.branch       and attendrpt.semester=j.semester
         and attendrpt.attenddate=j.attend_date and attendrpt.div=j.div;';`

```
        `x:=x+1;
  END LOOP;`
```

The problem here is it is conflicting the single quotes closing in query and the execute command.Is there anyway to solve this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, please *always* post a complete function. Your question is pointless without showing it all. And in a readable format.

Comment: @SJCET your edit removed Erwin's cleaned up formatting for your code and replaced it with the same(?) unreadable mess. Preview. Use the `{}` code indent button. Please show the *whole function* from `CREATE [OR REPLACE] FUNCTION` to the end semicolon.

Answer (score 2):

Quote your function definition with dollar-quoting (like `$BODY$` or just `$$`) as per the manual.

Use `execute ... using` instead of string substitution. For substituting identifiers use the `%I` format specifier from the `format` function.

If you absolutely must use `||` string concatenation, say if you're on some ancient version of PostgreSQL, you need to use the `quote_literal` and `quote_ident` functions to avoid issues with quoting and potential security problems.

Beyond that, it looks like the whole approach is completely unnecessary; you're doing something that looks like it can be done in simple SQL.

Comment: Thanks but I solved the issue using single quotes twice for inner quotes.